# Will O_NOBLOCK flag make file write() failure and In What case?

Tags: c, linux

I write about 50k bytes data to a file (which is stored in a USB disk and mount on  linux 2.6.37. FAT32 ) which using O_NOBLOCK every 200 ms.Whether the write() function has any risk of returning a EAGAIN.If yes, why and in what case. I run the program already half an hour, and no error return has been reported.

Comment: The fact that you haven't come across an EWOULDBLOCK yet is probably just because of the frequency of the write and the small size (~50k). I would code for the occurrence despite the low likelihood.

Answer (score 3):

Copy of correct-but-deleted answer:

No. The `O_NONBLOCK` flag doesn't affect working with regular files.

Comment: This is incorrect AFAICT. File systems may support non-blocking write, in which case `write()` may return `EAGAIN`. The `O_NONBLOCK` option also affects locking behavior.

Comment: In the specification of `select`: "A descriptor shall be considered ready for writing when a call to an output function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully." combined with "File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions." implies that `write` cannot fail with `EWOULDBLOCK` on regular files. An implementation where it does is therefore non-conforming and broken. Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html

Comment: Correct, R.., but it might have been prudent to note that in Linux, there is no way to be sure if the filesystem path you have open is a regular file or not. In some cases, like libraries or kernel modules that intercept `read()` and `write()` for security purposes -- or say just format or endian or transparent character set conversion -- that do not intercept the `stat()` family, it may not be possible to be sure the descriptor refers to a regular file. Then there are bind mounts and other such things. In other words, *it is always wrong to assume you have a regular file in Linux*.

Comment: No, `fstat` can tell you. If it lies you have a broken setup.

Comment: By the way, a "library or kernel modules that intercepts...for security purposes" any operation and modifies its behavior in such a way that it does not conform to its interface contract is **not enhancing security**, it's destroying security. No use of an interface that fails to satisfy its own interface contract can be secure.

Answer (score 0):

Some [reference](http://linux.die.net/man/3/write), for completeness:

That aplies only to pipes; for regular files, it's ignored.

> If the O_NONBLOCK flag is clear, a write request may cause the thread to block, but on normal completion it shall return nbyte.
>
> If the O_NONBLOCK flag is set, write() requests shall be handled differently, in the following ways:
>
> - The write() function shall not block the thread.
> - A write request for {PIPE_BUF} or fewer bytes shall have the following effect: if there is sufficient space available in the pipe, write() shall transfer all the data and return the number of bytes requested. Otherwise, write() shall transfer no data and return -1 with errno set to [EAGAIN].
> - A write request for more than {PIPE_BUF} bytes shall cause one of the following:
>
>   - When at least one byte can be written, transfer what it can and return the number of bytes written. When all data previously written to the pipe is read, it shall transfer at least {PIPE_BUF} bytes.
>   - When no data can be written, transfer no data, and return -1 with errno set to [EAGAIN].